# Передача instance в шаблон Django

Tags: python, django

Моя форма для редактирования поста. Я хочу что бы при выводе формы для редактирования показывались текущие значения полей, для этого я передаю instance в форму. Код view вот такой

```
@login_required
def post_edit(request, username: str, post_id: int):
"""This view edits the post by its id and saves changes in database."""
post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
form = PostForm(instance=post)
if post.author != request.user:
    return redirect('post', username, post_id)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('post', username, post_id)

return render(request, 'new.html', {"form": form, 'post': post})
```

Далее нужно в шаблоне вывести поля.
Вот мой код для отображения формы

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ field.label }}{% if field.field.required %}<span class="required">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
{{ field }}
{% if field.help_text %}
<small id="{{ field.id_for_label }}-help" class="form-text text-muted"><pre style="color: darkgreen;"> {{ field.help_text|safe }}</pre></small>
{% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Как сделать то же самое, не создавая форму два раза ?

Answer (score 1):

Может кому то пригодится
Решение вот такое :

```
form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)
```

Answer (score 1):

как указали в другом ответе
`form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)`
либо просто разнеси создание формы внутри `if...else`
в ветке `if` создаешь форму с `POST` данными, в ветке `else` создавай форму без POST

```
@login_required
def post_edit(request, username: str, post_id: int):
"""This view edits the post by its id and saves changes in database."""
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
    if post.author != request.user:
        return redirect('post', username, post_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('post', username, post_id)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)

    return render(request, 'new.html', {"form": form, 'post': post})
```